# Anylogic java.util.NoSuchElementException when using an overhead crane

Tags: anylogic

I am working on a model of manufacturing factory. An java.util.NoSuchElementException is thrown but unfortunately no more information is provided to understand the main cause of the problem. below is the some first line of error report:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList.getFirst(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.OverheadCraneController_xjal$b.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.OverheadCraneController_xjal$3.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.Shuttle_xjal.a(Unknown Source)
```

it seems that the problem is rooted in lack of an element in a list, but where and which one is not mentioned in the report. is there any way to understand what is the main cause? or any way to provide more information in error report?

I went to the step before where the exception is thrown and I found that the overhead crane which I use in the factory is some how at the brink of two different blocks of move by crane. can it be some sort of a reason of above error?

[image]

the above figure shows the two suspected move by crane blocks.

It would really be appreciated if someone can help me on this critical issue.

EDIT
[image]

the only blue link is as shown, when clicked next figure shows up.

[image]

which allow to add a break point, when i apply it, and then debug, no information is provided there too.

[image]

any
solution?

Comment: Are there any blue links in the error msg? If so, click on the first one to  see where it is caused

Comment: @Benjamin I add some info about it in next post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the root cause of the problem. As it is obvious in the below image, the first line of error call stack are about a linkedList lack of element and then it is about overhead crane.
[image]

So the most possible cause could be some sort of lack of seize block for crane utilization management perfectly. So I added a Delay block before each move by crane block in which dedicated crane availability is checked. if crane is available, delay stops itself, if not, the delay is stored in a collection of Delays where all delay blocks before each move by crane would be stored if the crane is not ready when they needed it.

on the other hand a cyclic event is considered to check whenever crane is free of any task and if there are some blocked Delays in the collection of delays stops their delay. a typical crane management system which solved my issue till now.

[image]

delay before each move by crane block and it code

[image]

code in the cyclic event

Comment: it seems that anylogic should consider some type of seize blocks for overhead cranes too in next releases.